# how to bind content-editable child to update the .length if a new element is added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few content-editable=true divs and have jquery adding a span after each paragraph in the editables and printing me the length of each paragraph

so far I have :

```
    $('.editable p').each(function(){
        $(this).append('<span>' + ($(this).text().length) + '</span>')
    });
```

however I don't know how to get this to update live  when editing & the enter key is pressed which adds a new paragraph or for when editing the text in the p itself

so far I have (!) :

```
    $('.editable').live().find('p');
    if ( $('.editable p > span').length > 0 ){
       $(this).append('<span>' + ($(this).text().length - $('span',this).text().length ) + '</span>')
    };

    $('.editable p').live().each(function(){
       $(this).hover(function(){ 
           $('span',this).replaceWith('<span>' + ($(this).text().length - $('span',this).text().length ) + '</span>');
       });
    });
```

but I don't know what to do because its not achieving results!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best what I came up with and still is far from perfect:

```
$(function () {
    $('.editable').on('keydown keypress keyup', function() {
        $(this).find('p').each(function () {
            var elem = $(this), length = elem.text().length;
            if (elem.has('span').length === 0) {
                elem.append('<span/>');
            }
            elem.find('span').text(length - length.toString().length);
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pepkin88/tMSBF/

I also tried adding spans after paragraphs. Effect wasn't better.
Adding new elements to contentEditable element causes strange behaviors, different in different browsers, it messes up with cursor. I think the best what you can do is to put lengths somewhere else in the document and display them in some other way (maybe position them to the end of the paragraphs).

Comment: Works you are a genius! I positioned them at the end of the paragraph with float, but if clicked apon they are editable as you said, So have added .attr('contentEditable',false) to the end of your code &  the spans not editable.

Comment: how could it work with copy & paste, if I add paste to the argument, it makes the paste into a span? which is not the desired result!

Comment: @webestdesigns I experimented a little with the code and it is still buggy on every browser when comes to multiple new lines in a row. Also do you want a lengths of paragraphs or lines, because it is a difference (paste code has `<br>`s in it).

Comment: thanks, I would want char per line, & thought the easiest way to do it is to use p elements so that hiting the return key would create a new line & create a new p, however I found that paste code on chrome adds a span & that paste as plain text seems to work, also I am trying to figure out how to delete a line meaning to convert to paragraphs into one, and hitting the backspace key on the first letter of a new p - behaves as the browsers back button! and delete at the end of the privious paragraph does nothing since the span is in the way and isn't editable! & I really appreciate your help

Comment: @webestdesigns So the easiest solution would be simple <textarea>. Here's an example: jsfiddle.net/pepkin88/cuNfJ/6/ . I put the numbers to the left. The solution is simple, quite quick (slower on larger texts), doesn't mess with cursor movement, works on every browser, pasted text works as it should, but updates depends on browser (I added listening for keypress, keyup, change and textinput events). Please, check it out.

Comment: Thanks I like what you have done, I think I will use that too, but Its easier for me to style normal divs with width background img on each char! and resizable & draggable! but could I use the same $('#lengths').html(arr.join('<br>')); outside an editable div too?

Comment: @webestdesigns My example relies on textarea and it's value attribute, which returns text with newlines. With editable div you get text without newlines, so the trick won't work. However you can parse the tree and calculate length manually, like you did til now. But you should remember about possibility of occurrence of not only `<p>` but also other block elements and `<br>`.

Comment: I will be using both in the end! the main content and a pasteboard so for that you have given me great help. thanks!